# Command to check cpu, memory, I/O and networking for a process

Tags: terminal, process, osx, io, top

I'm searching for a single OSX Command to check, at one time:

- CPU %
- MEMORY %
- I/O operations number
- Number of packets in and out

for a specific process.

I think **top** gives me only informations about cpu and memory for a single process, isn't it?

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy on Mac. You can try to install and run:

```
iostat 1
sar -n DEV -d -u 1 10
```

iostat shows only cpu and disk

sar shows disk, network and cpu. Memory only under Linux

Comment: Hi, so there is not a single command that gives me all those informations at one time? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want the sar or pidstat commands from the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/tutorial.html) package. Specifically, use `sar -A`. This command returns cpu, memory, and disk IO over the course of several hours.